# How to display activity without click on notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display the `activity` after notification came without clicking on the notification `Activity` has to be open. I am using `FCM` for notification sending.

How can I open `Activity` without clicking on the notification?

I am using this but it does not open the activity:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
String messageContent = "";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    messageContent = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    postToastMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


}

public void postToastMessage(final String message) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message +" received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, CallActivity.class);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(newIntent);

        }
    });
}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(" Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

I am getting this error

```
FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
```

Comment: And what kind of notification you are going to receive in `onTokenRefresh()`?

Comment: onTokenRefresh() it is given by firebase only

Comment: if you know any other please tell me. I will change

Comment: you need to use `FirebaseMessageService`

Comment: OP, go through this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService), we have to use **FirebaseMessagingService** to receive the notification's **RemoteMessage**, not **FirebaseInstanceIdService**.

Comment: I am Using that class also But log is not displaying in that .

Comment: Then you should just use those methods(  `showNotification("hi") and postToastMessage("hi")` ) inside that class. `FirebaseInstanceIdService` will only handle the token refresh events. While `FirebaseMessagingService` will facilitate your app to receive messages being sent from console or other appropriate means.

Comment: after changes also iam getting push notification only i want to open the activity

Comment: please find the changes above..........is this ok @when the morning comes

Comment: @Lassie, Yes, that's correct. Did you test it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161442/discussion-between-lassie-and-when-the-morning-comes).

Comment: Iam getting this error after i got the notification............
FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
may be it is helpful to you,

Add this code in onMessageReceived() method,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, NotificationActivity.class);//here put your activity name which you want to open
        intent.putExtra("isNotification", true);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I simple get message in NotificationActivity.class

```
 if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isNotification", false)) {
        message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        txt_message.setText(message);
    }
```

add this,

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessage receiveddd: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    //  Log.e(TAG, "onMessage notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e("notification background", String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData()));
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String deviceID = data.get("DeviceID");
        String message = data.get("Message");



        Log.e("value11111111", deviceID);
        Log.e("value222222222", message);


        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isNotification", true);
        // intent.putExtra("title", value1);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        //   sendNotification("message received");

    }
 }
```

Than from postman ,
   send this request

```
{
 "data":{
 "DeviceID":"",// pass here your DeviceID
 "Message":"hiiii" // pass here your message
},
"to":""// pass here ypur tocken
  }
```

Comment: Is onMessageReceived() method call ? put log in onMessageReceived() , Log.d("onMessage notification: " ,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

Comment: This works only if the application is active in the foreground. How to start the activity if the app is in the background?

Comment: Have you got any solution @Aparna

Comment: @Aparna u got solution? can you help?

Answer (score -1):

Make a BaseActivity in your code which extends AppComatActivity and all the other activity extends base activity, inside the show notification broadcast your intent with new activity and make a receiver in base activity, inside that receiver you can open your activity

For more conformation I can show how to code for this,

Thanks